# GetTypes() and TypeLoadException Error

Tags: c#, .net, typeloadexception

Is there a way to return only the types in a loaded assembly and not have it look for the nested ones so that the error TypeLoadException does not occur?

`foreach (var type in _assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass))`

Comment: Why can't the nested ones be loaded?

Comment: Provide the details of the exception please.

Comment: This code is in a utility program that checks the DLL for compliance, it doesn't expect the other DLLS to be loaded or needed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IsNested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnested.aspx) property of System.Type might help you to filter those out.

You could also use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to browse the assemblies if you do not need to load them.

> Cecil is a library written by Jb Evain
>   (http://evain.net/blog/) to generate
>   and inspect programs and libraries in
>   the ECMA CIL format. It has full
>   support for generics, and support some
>   debugging symbol format.
>
> In simple English, with Cecil, you can
>   load existing managed assemblies,
>   browse all the contained types, modify
>   them on the fly and save back to the
>   disk the modified assembly.